# "Ball of the foot" em português do Brasil

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês

Qual a tradução correta, para português do Brasil, da expressão inglesa "ball of the foot"? Segundo [The Free dictionary, "ball of the foot" é:](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Ball+of+the+foot)

> the padded portion of the sole, which overlies the heads of the metatarsals, on which the weight rests when the heel is raised.
>
> [Em português] a parte almofadada da planta do pé em volta das cabeças dos metatarsos, sobre a qual o peso do corpo se apoia quando se levanta o calcanhar.

Penso que seria "raiz do dedão", mas estou com dúvidas. Podem-me esclarecer?

Comment: Acho importante explicar o que significa a expressão original, para facilitar a obtenção de respostas.

Comment: "the weight should be on the ball of the foot". Obrigado Jacinto.

Comment: É a parte entre a palma e os dedos, aqueles nozinhos. Não só a raiz do dedão, mas dos dedos todos. Mas não sei como se chama isso, nem sequer em português de Portugal...

Comment: Frederico, não tens de que agradecer. Na verdade essa frase foi colocada lá pelo @ANeves. Eu substituí-a agora por uma definição completa, com link à fonte da definição

Comment: @frederico, Já agora, se clicares no "edited X mins ago/x hours ago" na base da tua pergunta, podes ver exatamente quem é que mudou o quê na pergunta. E, claro está, podes clicar no "edit" no canto inferior esquerdo e voltar a editar a pergunta à tua vontade.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que colaboraram na minha tentativa de traduzir "ball of the foot" : tdmsoares, ANeves, Jacinto, gmauch. Como explicitou o Jacinto, não era uma definição que eu pretendia mas uma expressão que traduzisse a ideia. A que me parece mais simples e que se adapta melhor ao contexto parece ser "ponta do pé". Uma vez mais obrigado tdmsoares.

Comment: @frederico De nada! Na verdade tenho de agradecer pela pergunta e comentários, acabo aprendendo mais com todos!

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(anatomy)), a expressão *Ball of the foot* é a junção entre o corpo do pé e os dedos do pé.

Anatomicamente falando, é a região onde há a cabeça dos metatarsos (ossos que fazem a junçâo entre os ossos do calcanhar aos ossos do dedo)

Como o Jacinto citou nos comentários, na wikipedia cita "Bola do Pé" esta região, o que aparecia ser uma tradução literal, encontrei em outras fontes relacionando esta região com "Bola do Pé". Algumas delas:

- [Fisioterapia para todos](http://www.fisioterapiaparatodos.com/p/dor-no-pe/): cita Bola do Pé, mas nomeia a região de "Ponta do Pé"
- [Clínica Movere](http://clinicamovere.com.br/http://clinicamovere.com.br/?ortopedia=metatarsalgia-calosidades-plantares)

Ambos relacionam a região com a doença *metatarsalgia*

Aparentemente, "bola do pé" não é comum de se ouvir, mas essa é a mais usada tradução dessa área do pé, do que usar um termo "regiâo da cabeça dos metatarsos"...

Comment: Mas*ball of the foot* refere-se não tanto ao ossos, como à parte exterior. O Merriam-Webster diz até que é a parte da planta do pé nessa zona.

Comment: Editei acrescentando que é a região desses ossos do pé, pois dava o sentido de somente ossos. O interessante é que falando de metacarpo e metatarso temos a ideia de osso, enquanto falando em falange, há a ideia de parte dos dedos...

Comment: Concordo. Eu vi numa página da Wikipédia (sobre todo o pé, creio) a expressão *bola do pé*. A fonte era um manual publicado no Brasil, mas os autores pareciam ser de língua inglesa. Portanto deve ter sido uma tradução palavra a palavra. Parece não haver nome consagrado em português.

Comment: @Jacinto Tem razão! Eu nunca vi alguém falar "bola do pé"... Acho que o mais próximo que podemos falar aqui é "base dos dedos"

Comment: Não sei se *base dos dedos do pé* não será ambíguo. Não se poderá pensar que é a parte inferior dos dedos, que toca no solo ou sola do sapato? Eu não sou avesso  a neologismos como *bola do pé*.  Num documento técnico poder-se-ia começar por definir *bola-do-pé* (se realmente não existe nome em português) e usar o neologismo a partir daí. Não sei é se isto serve as necessidades do OP.

Comment: A pergunta pede uma tradução. Esta resposta explica (e bem) o que é "ball of the foot", mas não oferece uma tradução.

Answer (score 0):

Pela definição, "bola do pé" é aquela região que suporta o nosso peso quando levantamos os calcanhares, isto é, uma região de mais ou menos 6-7 centímetros vizinha aos artelhos (dedos do pé).

Não usamos a expressão "bola do pé" para descrever essa região no Brasil.  Dizemos "o calcanhar/região calcânea", "a planta do pé ou região plantar" e "os dedos dos pés/artelhos/pododáctilos"   Pododáctilos é um termo médico, "artelhos" é um pouco erudito. O povo diz mesmo é "dedos dos pé".